# How to trigger lambda-local command from .js file in a nodejs application

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using a *nodejs* application and 
w.r.t this link :- http://blog.rowanudell.com/testing-serverless-functions-locally/.

I was able to call the lambda function locally with the command : `$ lambda-local  -f index.js` on *CLI*.

Is there a way to trigger the same from inside a *.js* file of *nodejs* application?

Comment: You can exec any external command using https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html. Would that work for you, or do you need it to be via code that you've imported (e.g. as a required node module)?

Answer (score 1):

This should do the job:

```
// set the event data you want here
const event = {};
// mock the context if needed here
const context = {};
// retrieve the result of the lambda here
const cb = (err, res) => {
  console.log(err, res);
};

// load the file containing the Lambda handler
const lambda = require("./path/to/index.js");
// call the handler
lambda.handler(event, context, cb);
```

Comment: Yes, this works from server side code(or nodejs terminal). However, I want to invoke lambda function from client side code (angularjs code). anythoughts? Is there any way to host my lambda function locally hit that from angularjs client side code?

Comment: The question was about *"inside a .js file of nodejs application"*, so I guess this is another question. If you want to expose a Lambda to be able to call it from a browser, you should use [API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html). I do not understand what you mean by *"to host my lambda function **locally** hit that from angularjs client side code"*.

Comment: You should call API gateway from your Angular application and not try to execute the lambda *locally*. Otherwise, you'll have to run a Node.js app that simulates API Gateway and calls the function. I would recommend to create a Lambda and an API endpoint for development purpose in AWS.

Comment: Yes, the lambda function will be called via APIGateway. So, is there a way to setup the APIGateway locally? I tried using localstack (as described in https://github.com/atlassian/localstack) , and was able to create lambda function locally(on linux machine); but, not able to configure APIGateway.